# Unable to call derived class function using base class pointers

Tags: c++

I want to call a derived class function that isn't defined in the base class using base class pointers. but this always raises the error:

```
error C2039: ‘derivedFunctionName’ : is not a member of ‘BaseClass’
```

Do you know how I could get around this?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show us the related code?

Comment: That's a bad design, no less.

Comment: class Material
{
public:
 void foo()
 {
  cout << "Class Material";
 }
};

class Unusual_Material : public Material
{
public:
 void fooo()
 {
  cout << "Class Unusual_Material";
 }
};

int main()
{
 Material strange = Unusual_Material();
 strange.foo0();  

 return 0;
}

Comment: Maybe I am a little late, but @BartekBanachewicz would you mind explaining why it is bad design?

Comment: @Tu.ma Because a code written in terms of the base class should have no expectations on the derived type being used. Either the function should be present on the base, or the derived type should be used instead.

Answer (score 15):

You *can't* call a member that appears only in a derived class through a pointer to the base class; you have to cast it (probably using `dynamic_cast`) to a pointer to the derived type, first -- otherwise the compiler has no idea the method even exists.

It might look something like this:

```
void someMethod(Base* bp) {
    Derived *dp = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(bp);
    if (dp != null)
        dp->methodInDerivedClass();
}
```

Comment: using dynamic_cast how can i call a function that is reside in derived class Ernest Friedman-Hill.. if you explained with example means its much more easier to get it.. thanks

Comment: @SujeethDamodharan I added an example.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to make the function `virtual` in the base class and then override it in the derived class.  You don't have to define the function in the base class (although you can), but you can use the pure virtual syntax in the base class `virtual void foo() = 0;`  if you don't want to provide an implementation in the base class.

This will let you override it in the derived class and still call it in the base class through a base class pointer. This is known as 'polymorphism'.

You can also just cast it to a derived type at run time if you are sure it is actually a derived class pointer at that time. If it is not, it will crash.

Comment: yes i agree.. but with our using virtual keyword is there any possible way to do this??? thanks..

Comment: Yes, as I noted in my answer, you can cast it to a derived type at run time if you are sure it is actually a derived class pointer.  `dynamic_cast` also works, but it is SLOW.  In the end, it is better to use good design practices (i.e. polymorphism) rather than going the casting route.   Casting works but will lead to brittle code and more maintenance in the end.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy - Maybe I'm missing something, but if you are using the pure virtual syntax on the `foo` function in the base class, you make the base class abstract, which is not neccessarly what you wanted in the first place, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You can call a derived class member through a pointer to a base class as long as the method is virtual.  That's what polymorphism is about.

In order for that to work you must declare a virtual method (probably pure virtual) in the base class and overload it in the derived class.

Note that you will run into issues calling the derived member from the base method.  Do some ARM or Meyers reading if this doesn't make sense to you.